# iterating a multidimensional List

Tags: apex, list, iteration

I am trying to recieve a email with an attachment (CSV FIle) and have it iterate through the csv and upsert it as records in a custom object. i upload the document by hand daily. PAIN!

i am using a csv parsing class i have found in [Salesforce Code Samples](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples) that makes the body of the csv into a multidimensional List. which is great but i dont know how to properly iterate through the list data without nesting too many *for* loops inside each other. which i dont want to do.

```
Global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env) {

    Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] bAttachments = email.BinaryAttachments; 
    string csvBody = null;  
    list<list<string>> parsedCsvData = new list<list<string>>();
    List<Wholesale_Pipeline__c> lstPipe = new List<Wholesale_Pipeline__c();

    String mySubject = email.subject.toLowerCase();
    String s = 'Byte Report';
    Boolean reportName;
    reportName = mySubject.contains(s);



    if (reportName == true) {

        try {
            if(bAttachments != null){
                for(Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment btt : bAttachments){
                    if(btt.filename.endsWith('.csv')){
                        csvBody.btt.body.toString();
                    }
                }
                if(csvBody != null){
                    parsedCsvData = parseCSV.ParseCSV(csvBody, true);
                }
                if(!parsedCsvData.isEmpty()){
                    for(list<list<string>> parsedLoop : parsedCsvData){

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }                    
}
```

if i add: inside the first loop to iterate

```
for(string s1 : parsedLoop){    
    for(integer i = 0; i < parser.size(); i++){
       Wholesale_Pipeline__c pipe = new Wholesale_Pipeline__c();
       pipe.name = s1[0];
       lstPipe.add(pipe);
    }
 }
```

it just seems to excessive to add that many loops inside each other, if that is the only way then i will do so. but can anyone help and maybe show me another technique of how i can accomplish iterating these lists. as well as updating records with these lists.

CSV Parser:

```
public static List<List<String>> parseCSV(String contents,Boolean skipHeaders) {
    List<List<String>> allFields = new List<List<String>>();

    // replace instances where a double quote begins a field containing a comma
    // in this case you get a double quote followed by a doubled double quote
    // do this for beginning and end of a field
    contents = contents.replaceAll(',"""',',"DBLQT').replaceall('""",','DBLQT",');
    // now replace all remaining double quotes - we do this so that we can reconstruct
    // fields with commas inside assuming they begin and end with a double quote
    contents = contents.replaceAll('""','DBLQT');
    // we are not attempting to handle fields with a newline inside of them
    // so, split on newline to get the spreadsheet rows
    List<String> lines = new List<String>();
    try {
        lines = contents.split('\n');
    } catch (System.ListException e) {
        System.debug('Limits exceeded?' + e.getMessage());
    }
    Integer num = 0;
    for(String line : lines) {
        // check for blank CSV lines (only commas)
        if (line.replaceAll(',','').trim().length() == 0) break;

        List<String> fields = line.split(',');  
        List<String> cleanFields = new List<String>();
        String compositeField;
        Boolean makeCompositeField = false;
        for(String field : fields) {
            if (field.startsWith('"') && field.endsWith('"')) {
                cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));
            } else if (field.startsWith('"')) {
                makeCompositeField = true;
                compositeField = field;
            } else if (field.endsWith('"')) {
                compositeField += ',' + field;
                cleanFields.add(compositeField.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));
                makeCompositeField = false;
            } else if (makeCompositeField) {
                compositeField +=  ',' + field;
            } else {
                cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));
            }
        }

        allFields.add(cleanFields);
    }
    if (skipHeaders) allFields.remove(0);
    return allFields;       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're going to need two loops. That's the price you pay for having to parse a two-dimensional list. The trick is to put the record you're creating *outside* the inner loop. However, since you also have a header row (typically), you usually want to remove that one first.

```
String[] headers = parsedCsvData.remove(0);
Wholesale_Pipeline__c[] records = new Wholesale_Pipeline__c[0];
for(String[] row: parsedCsvData) {
  Wholesale_Pipeline__c record = new Wholesale_Pipeline__c();
  for(Integer index = 0, size = headers.size(); index < size; index++) {
    // Simplified, you need to actually parse the data types
    record.put(headers[index], row[index]);
  }
  records.add(record);
}
insert records;
```

Comment: i edited the post to include the csv parser

Comment: i can have the parser keep the headers, but they will in no way match the salesforce field names. so can i create a dummy header that will match the fields? and if so how can i go about that?

Comment: i dont understand what im supposed to do?

Comment: @BryanCerrati if they don't match, you'll need to arrange for a way the user or something to make the fields

Comment: how can i set a static header?

Comment: the csv comes from a third party i dont have access to it until it comes over.

Comment: i get : System.SObjectException: Illegal assignment from String to Date

Comment: i dont understand how to parse data types within the loop

Comment: @BryanCerrati Yes, you need to identify the data type and try to parse it via Date.valueOf, DateTime.valueOf, Boolean.valueOf, etc. Have a look at [this post](http://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2016/01/converting-xml-to-native-objects.html) I wrote, it's not *directly* going to help you, but it should (probably) be useful to see how you might dynamically detect the base type of a string based on the input value.

Comment: since im looping through how would i know where to put date.valueof if i wanted to hardcode where they would go? do i say if index is 6 then _date.valueOf(row[index])_